# Why doesn’t Xcode argument completion filter suggestions by type?

Tags: xcode, code-completion

Let’s say I have the following code:

```
- (void) handlePanGesture: (UIPanGestureRecognizer*) sender
{
    CGPoint foo = [sender translationInView:XXX];
}
```

Now when I place the cursor at the point marked as `XXX` and press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get a list of completion suggestions, Xcode happily suggests all sensible symbols regardless of their type (including `NSArray*`, `CGSize`, or even `SEL`). Since Xcode presumably has enough information to know the argument type, why doesn’t it filter the suggestions down to only those compatible with `UIView*`?

Comment: I don't see any technical reason why they couldn't do it - or at least order it so that `UIView*` suggestions appear up top first. I'm guessing it's a "we haven't gotten there yet".

Comment: +1 for question. What happens if xxx is an undirect UIView? As in CGPoint foo = [sender translationInView:[NSArray objectAtIndex:1]];

Comment: The `XXX` sign just marks the cursor position, there’s nothing there. Therefore Xcode just suggests all sensible symbols from the current scope and there’s no problem with the code you wrote.